# Apache RewriteEngine Fallback from HTTPS to HTTP failing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Linux Debian 7.8 Server running Apache and PHP5.4.36-0+deb7u3. The web site root is the default /var/www/

The site has a login page and then other folders, php pages etc. Primarily I only wanted the login page, (identification.php), page to be forced to HTTPS.  So I setup and configured the RewriteEngine.

I have a .htaccess file in the document root with the contents shown below.  My problem is if the user clicks on http://www.example.com/identification.php it's correctly converted to HTTPS.  But, if after login they then navigate to another page its also delivered as HTTPS which isn't what I want. I thought my .htaccess config forced other pages back to HTTP.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Everything exept that identification.php page must be delivered in HTTP.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/identification\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/identification\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why you should go back to http. Once the initial https connection is made there really isn't any signification speed issues. I serve my whole site with https as do many large sites now. IMO it's kind of a waste of time to go back and forth.

Comment: Because its for a Photo Video Gallery.  Part of the Gallery is videos which stream over HTML5 using http://www.videojs.com/   Problem is whilst they play perfectly over HTTPS on laptop browsers,  Our friends at apple dont allow HTML5 videos to play on ios devices through videojs plugin without the site having a signed Intermediate certificate and a signed certificate.  Thats why :)  So the fix is to make the login HTTPS so passwords arent sent in clear text and HTTP for the Video part of the site :)